# How to generate all color into individual pixel?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I can generate all black pixel by stacking 3 np.zeros([1,1,1]) together

But why not this?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

m  = np.zeros([8,32,1])

k = 0 
for i in range(m.shape[0]):
    for j in range(m.shape[1]):
        for z in range(m.shape[2]):
            m[i,j,z] = k
            k+=1
a = np.stack(m,m,m)

cv2.imwrite('rgb.png',a)
```

## Error

```
axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, result_ndim)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do stacking 3D arrays: `a=np.stack(m,m,m)`?

Comment: Also, the syntax is `np.stack((m,m,m), axis=-1)`

Comment: I want to generate each color as a pixel

Comment: That's your overall goal, not the specific command. With this piece of code, you're generating different grayscale level.

Comment: @QuangHoang wasn't stacking [8,32,1] 3 times will become [8,32,3]? By merging those grayscale I will get RGB color

Comment: No, it becomes `[8,32, 1, 3]`. And exactly my point, three channels of same intensity give different levels of gray.

Comment: What should I do to make it [8,32,3]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I modified your code a bit to show how it works:

```
m  = np.zeros([8,32])

k = 0 
for i in range(m.shape[0]):
    for j in range(m.shape[1]):
        m[i,j] = k
        k+=1
a = np.stack((m,m,m), axis=-1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why it doesn't generate RGB colors? 

Because I used r,g,b = cv2.split

each plane is grayscale 

so combining each plane I should get RGB right?

Comment: You do get `RGB`, but since you stack the same array across the three channels, i.e. `r=g=b`, the result image only have gray colors.